# How to uninstall SaltyBeer Skype call recorder?

Tags: macos, skype, pkg

I wanted to test [SaltyBeer](http://www.saltybeer.com/download.html) Skype Call recorder. So I downloaded `saltybeer-mac-installer.pkg` and installed it on my OS X 10.11.6. Now when I open Skype, it opens SaltyBeer automatically.

Now I want to uninstall it, but no icon is added to `/Applications/`. There is no instruction to uninstall in the product website. I tried [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), but there was no luck. Also, there is no process named `saltybeer` in the running processes:

```
$ ps -ef | grep saltybeer
$
```

How can I uninstall SaltyBeer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/525395/541820) answer:

I found package ID with `pkgutil`:

```
$ pkgutil --packages | grep saltybeer
com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer
```

To find out paths of installed payload:

```
$ pkgutil --files com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer
Contents
Contents/Info.plist
Contents/MacOS
Contents/MacOS/saltybeer
plugins
plugins/saltybeer.bundle
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/MacOS
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/cocoa_ui
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Resources
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Resources/._Info.plist
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Resources/Info.plist
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature
plugins/saltybeer.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
```

Then to find out the location of installation:

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer
package-id: com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer
version: 2.0
volume: /
location: Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/saltybeer.plugin
install-time: 1477419357
```

I changed the current working directory:

```
$ cd /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/saltybeer.plugin
```

And deleted installed files:

```
$ pkgutil --only-files --files com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rm -if
```

And directories:

```
$ pkgutil --only-dirs --files com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer | tail -r | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rmdir
```

Then I removed package receipt:

```
$ sudo pkgutil --forget com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer
Forgot package 'com.saltybeer.pkg.saltybeer' on '/'.
```

and finally to remove plugin directory:

```
$ cd /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL
$ sudo rm -rf saltybeer.plugin
```

Done!

Comment: In addition to your answer there is a great tool with you can inspect contents of packages: [Suspicious package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/)

Comment: Thanks, @dante12. "suspicious package" is useful. Although OS X installer has a "Show Files" feature that shows contents of the package, but not exact paths. Instead, this application provides complete information.